# Making textbox transparent and getting half border colour

Tags: html, css

this is my link:
http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/Leo63eud/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="your email" class="email" />

.email {
    background-image:url('assets/images/email.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border:0px solid #7ac9b7;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    border-bottom:2px solid red!important;
}
```

half of the line should be in red and other half in grey,,also the image icon is not showing.. m not getting.. please help

Comment: Half of what line(s) should be grey/red? I'd strongly suggest adding an image to your question to show your desired output.

Comment: i cannot add the image,, if u can help me in doing that,, it will be great

Comment: half of the line thats below "your email".. thats what i am trying to change

Comment: And what image should I add on your behalf? You first have to help us to help you.

Comment: sir i am not able to upload image,, i am new in stackoverflow and i must have 10 reputations to add image.. is there any other way to add image??

Answer (score 0):

The image does not show because you had background set to none at the bottom of your email style. This line `background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;`

I left the `background-color` of the input to show you more clear with the borders. You just change this line `background-color: #dcdcdc;` to `background-color: transparent;`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Leo63eud/6/)
[**DEMO2** (with icon image)](http://jsfiddle.net/Leo63eud/7/)

```
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="your email" class="email" />
    <div class="input-container_border-red"></div>
    <div class="input-container_border-gray"></div>
</div>

.input-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-container_border-red {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
}

.input-container_border-gray {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.email {
    background-image:url('/assets/images/email.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    border:none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy got it.. but still image is not showing,, what should i edit??

Comment: You mean it does not show up in the fiddle or your own code? I'm sure it's something with the path to the image. Look at my updated answer. Added `/assets....`

Comment: the path is all right,, i got responsive, but image part is still not coming,,

Comment: @user3752467 I'm sure its something wrong with your path or image. look at my answer update.